# setInterval() in EJS template does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, ejs

I'm currently stuck with a problem in a homework project. I'm trying to make a project where the price of bitcoin will update every second. Now the API request is working fine and I can see the data render from an EJS template but I can't make the price update every second. Can anyone check my code and see if anything is wrong in my code? For reference please check www.preev.com. It shows how I want the price to be updated. And also check below my code.

I have tried to call the API request in app.js file and rendered it in an EJS template called results.ejs.

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");


app.set("view engine", "ejs");


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    request("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true&include_last_updated_at=true", function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("result", {data: data});
        }
    });
});




app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server has started");
});
```

results.ejs

```
<h1>
    Bitcoin Latest
</h1>



Price: $ <span id="showPrice"></span> 
<br>
MarketCap: $<%= data["bitcoin"]["usd_market_cap"] %>
<br>
24h Volume: $<%= data["bitcoin"]["usd_24h_vol"] %>
<br>
24h Change: <%= data["bitcoin"]["usd_24h_change"] %>%


<script>
    function updatePrice(){
        document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML= <%= data["bitcoin"]["usd"] %>;
    };

    setInterval(updatePrice, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: That ejs document is processed on the server when the user visits the page, which means "ejs code" like `<%= data["bitcoin"]["usd"] %>` runs exactly once, then never again until the page is refreshed. You need to create a second route in your express app that sends back only the usd value, then request that from your script using `fetch()`.

Comment: the second route you mentioned, I have to make API request again and get the USD value only? Can't I edit the first and use the usd value only?

Comment: You need a second route because the first is sending the result view / HTML document. Use something like `app.get("/usd", ...` and `res.sendJSON(data.bitcoin.usd);`, then use `fetch('/usd').then(r => r.json()).then(usd => document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML = usd);` in your client side script.

Comment: If the API supports CORS, you can of  course make the API request directly from the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initial answer

Your setInterval works fine, it's just that inside your function the data never changes.

To fix it you have to reference a variable (of which the content changes), rather than hardcoding the value in your function.

### Extra explanation

For example you are using EJS, which is a *templating language*. A templating language parses output based on your variables (once per page load).

Your template line

```
document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML= <%= data["bitcoin"]["usd"] %>;
```

parses into

```
document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML= 9624.46;
```

And your interval then updates the `innerHTML` of `#showPrice` with that value, every `500` ms.

What you probably mean to do is make the request from the client (the browser), then store its response into a variable, say `latestResult`, and then code your function to reference that variable, like so:

```
document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML= latestResult;
```

### Example implementation

This means that your express application (app.js) will render `result` without data:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('result');
});
```

And the request part will be in your template:

```
function updateLatestPrice() {
  fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true&include_last_updated_at=true').then((result) => {
    const latestResult = result.bitcoin.usd

    document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML = latestResult || 'failed'
  })
}

setInterval(updateLatestPrice, 3000)
```

> Note that I changed `request` into `fetch` here because I couldn't be sure whether your client code has babel, so I went with the browser's native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Hi @Zak, I have updated my answer to describe what is happening in more detail.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now. But as far as I've understood, I can make the request from client side, store it in a variable and use that variable in my express app? Is that it?

Comment: If you mean whether or not you can declare this in your EJS file, then yes; the whole `request` part will be in your ejs file, so that your browser can make the request instead of the server.

Comment: I understand completely now. but I have a last question. To make a request from client side(in my case in ejs file), I have to do it by using fetch() right?

Comment: Correct, I updated my answer to be a bit more complete.